# How to have an ms teams bot process the payload of a messageback card action

Tags: node.js, microsoft-teams

Looking for a node.js example of a bot processing the payload of a messageback card action.
The card appears valid and I see the displayText echoed back when I press the button.

And I get a valid 200 code back.

But, can't find an example of the bot processing the payload when the button is clicked.

```json
{
    "type": "Action.Submit",
    "title": "Click me for messageBack",
    "data": {
        "msteams": {
        "type": "messageBack",
        "displayText": "I clicked this button",
        "text": "text to bots",
        "value": "{\"bfKey\": \"bfVal\", \"conflictKey\": \"from value\"}"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you click on card button it will send a message back which is mentioned in the displayed text, and you will receive on message activity event, there you can handle the code. You will receive the payload value under activity.

Comment: @dennis, Are you still facing the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

For better understanding copying comments to answer:

When you click on card button it will send a message back which is mentioned in the displayed text, and you will receive on message activity event, there you can handle the code. You will receive the payload value under activity